# How to access an ItemAppearance from ListView in Delphi 10?

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey

As shown in this image below, I need to select the value of the `txtID` field when clicking on the item in the ListView. How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1ItemClick(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
  showmessage(AItem.Objects[1].Data.AsString);  // Value of field
  showmessage(AItem.Objects[1].Name);  // Name of field

// OR

  showmessage(AItem.Data['txtID'].AsString);  // Value of field
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{$R *.fmx}

procedure Form1.ListView1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ListView1.Selected <> nil
  then Label2.Text := TAppearanceListViewItem(ListView1.Selected).Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('txtID').Text
  else Label2.Text := '-';
//If you change the selected item with keyboard (up, down, left, right), then you will get back the selected value, without clicking on it.
end;
```